# Making UI for console application

Tags: c#, c++, c, user-interface, console-application

How can I make an interface for console applications to make them look like `edit.com` under Microsoft's operating systems. Target languages are C, C++ and C#.NET.

[image: MS-DOS Editor]

Comment: `<conio.h>`, `<ncurses.h>`? Google for them. Have no idea about `C#`

Comment: To clarify, the OP did say, C, C++, but C#... dunno about that.... to the OP, are you writing it in C/C++?

Comment: may I ask why you need a console GUI? especially for .NET, a proper GUI is probably much easier to implement.

Comment: I don't really want to make an application. I was just wondering about how it's done.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29):
e.g.:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/curses-sharp/

Answer (score 2):

That would be based on a very simple framework which writes directly to the video to draw the underlying shadows, drop down menus, etc, not alone that, since 'Edit.com` would be written in assembler for speed in relation to drawing, this is quite ancient by today's standards, you can however take a look at [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.org/) which will enable you to do this kind of thing.

The neat beauty is, PDCurses is compatible with the unix equivalent of Curses.

But, really, today, it is all about GUI and Windows....

What kind of application are you trying to do?

IIRC, from my old days, there was an object orientated framework for this using [TurboVision](http://tvision.sourceforge.net/), which has a port available with open source now, see this wikipedia entry on this [TurboVision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Vision).

Comment: your link to pdcurses is broken

Answer (score 1):

Today, console applications are either old DOS applications emulated more and less in Windows, or command-line interpreters.
Anyway, if you really want to do an editor, use the `System.Console` class in the `System NameSpace` and use the `SetCursorPosition` method to write what you want where you want

Answer (score 0):

The edit.com window you are showing appear to be developed with [Turbo Vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Vision), an old console gui library written by Borland many years ago.

Borland put the software in public domain and release its C++ sources. There is also a porting to Pascal, developed by the community, called [Free Vision](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Free_Vision).

Unfortunately ,I don't think there is a porting or a wrapper to dot.net, so you have to write your own. Or, at least, you can look at the sources to get inspired...

Comment: Anyone found/tried a .net port for turbo vision?

Comment: The edit.com window in OP is not Turbo Vision - that's the MS text mode interface, used by the edit.com editor, QB, MS C++, VB for DOS, etc.