# Full Old-School TUI Command Line Application in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have coded a high performance real-time data data processor, and I have spent WAY too much time trying to make the GUI not to freeze, be responsive, etc. (using async invoke and other gui best practices).
However, my team and I decided to move to a plain old simple and efficient Text-User-Interface and get rid of all the bells and whistles for more efficiency and performance.

So I would like to create a console app that is similar to command lines apps like *sql* or *telnet*.
I know how to manage basic arguments and console read/write, but I was wondering how these apps work.
 Is there something specific about it ? Just a matter of curiosity. Can I display something like:

```
MYAPP>Run command1 -arg1 -arg2
     >Success !
MYAPP>Show Log
     >...
MYAPP>Run command2 -arg1 -arg2
     etc.
```

is the "MYAPP>" prefix just something to be parsed plainly or is there a smarter way to do that ?

**EDIT**
I have Stumbled upon this [TUI library](http://tui.codeplex.com/) (pic below). But it not complete and not maintained anymore.
If somebody know of something similar I welcome any suggestion.

[image]

**EDIT 2** 
curse library seems interesting too, as stated in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699784/making-ui-for-console-application)

Comment: maybe you should write your own powershell provider ? you'll get for free all the console environment, which is very powerful (well named)

Comment: What your describing is something like a REPL which isn't to difficult to make yourself. Definitely easier than diving into powerhell. If the input becomes more like sql your problem won't be with the interface but with parsing the input.

Comment: @the_ajp Yes I Agree on that. I was just wondering if there was some more advanced lib with nice features

Comment: I really hate being down-voted with no comment/nor explanation. This suck dude ! :-/

Answer (score 2):

The [ConsoleDraw](https://github.com/Haydend/ConsoleDraw) library could be of used here. 
 

It's similar to the TUI library you mentioned, but with more controls and still maintained. It is possible to add your own custom controls if you needed them also.